# What's the difference between the terms Electronics and Electrical?

Tags: education

So can anybody tell about what's the difference between the terms Electronics and Electrical ? How do we differentiate them from one another?

Answer (score 4):

A computer, and an amplifier, are obviously electronic. An alternator, and a filament light bulb, are obviously electrical.

These are shorthand descriptions for areas of technology.

Somewhere in between is a grey area that legions of people enjoy wasting large amounts of time arguing about the demarcation line between the two. This line is not relevant, or can even be demonstrated to exist.

Comment: but on what basis will you differentiate them from one another?

Comment: You don't. You don't need to! Leave differentiation to people who write text books on 'electronics' and then argue about what should and should not be included with people who write text books on 'electrical'. If you want to study a computer made from electromechanical relays, who cares whether you call it electronic or electrical. I think many people would say active 'gain' denotes electronic, but then what would you call a magnetic amplifier, or a hydraulic amplifier? Chill. Let go of the urge to classify. Observe what is.

Comment: Even the "obvious" examples are not 100% one or the other. Very large proportion of computers contain electric motors for fans etc. Automotive alternators contain diode rectifiers and have electronic voltage regulators. Large synchronous generators (alternators) contain electronic circuitry to provide brushless excitation. Even some vacuum cleaners now have electronic motor controllers and have been given the dubious name "digital motors." The word "transformer" is now being used to describe electronic voltage converters." Even my heart is electronically augmented.

Answer (score 2):

Electronics deals with circuits based on semiconductors. Purely electric circuits do not have semiconductors.

Then of course, with time, the limit has become fuzzy. A fan, a washing machine and a vacuum cleaner are clear examples of electric appliances, but all of them have a fair amount of electronic circuits to control them.

Comment: Nice try. Problem is, people still occasionally use vacuum tubes.

Comment: That's right. So maybe an exact definition would be that electronics are based on vacuum tubes, semiconductors... and all sort of other electronic devices :)

Comment: Actually, you're close to right, even though you're joking. The distinction has historical distortions which make a clean definition almost impossible.